# ZK zul iterate over a enummap to populate a grid

Tags: java, enums, zk

I have a problem in populating a grid using an EnumMap as bind:

```
<grid sizedByContent="true" span="true" model="@bind(vm.pendingRequests[RequestType.RETURN])" 
emptyMessage="Nessuna richiesta trovata" height="100%" width="100%">
```

In the view model there is the declaration of the map:

```
private Map<RequestType, List<PendingRequest>> pendingRequests;
```

Where RequestType is an enum:

```
public enum RequestType {
    EXIT("exit"),
    RETURN("return"),
    PARKING("park");

    private final String description;

    private RequestType(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public static RequestType getEnum(String value) {
        if (value == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        for (RequestType v : values()) {
            if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(v.getDescription())) {
                return v;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Do you know where I'm wrong in populating the grid using an EnumMap and bind?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there an error message from ZK?

Comment: no errors from ZK, it appears the empty message as there were no data in the map.

Comment: Do you have a public getter for `pendingRequests` ?

Comment: yes, but it seems it is a problem strictly related to Enums... I tried to use RequestType.RETURN as a parameter in a command and the method received a null value.

Comment: I did as you suggested me: I moved my solution to an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion of @bidifx I changed the zul in this way:

```
<grid sizedByContent="true" span="true" model="@load(vm.getPendingRequests('RETURN'))" 
       emptyMessage="Nessuna richiesta trovata" height="100%" width="100%">
```

And in the view model I created a method that returned directly the list to the zul:

```
public List<PendingRequest> getPendingRequests(String stype) {
        RequestType type = RequestType.valueOf(stype);
        return pendingRequests.get(type);
    }
```

This worked for me.
Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2):

So here we go:

You can not directly access `static` class members. This also applies to `enum` which is in some way the same. So you have to use this little workaround...

1. create a getter for your enum item:

   ```
   public EnumType getTypeItem() {
     return EnumType.Item;
   }
   ```
2. use this getter in your `ZUL`

   ```
   <label value="@load(vm.typeItem)">
   ```